# Scroll to element on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to make it possible to scroll to a certain element by pressing a certain key. In my example I have only the code for 'h' to bring the page back to the home section. However, nothing happens when 'h' is pressed.

I have used code similar to this without using a keypress and am wondering why this code isn't working. There are no errors.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4d34L89f/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var speed = 1.5;
    var home = $('#home').scrollTop();
    var one = $('#one').scrollTop();
    var two = $('#two').scrollTop();
    var three = $('#three').scrollTop();
    var four = $('#four').scrollTop();
    var five = $('#five').scrollTop();
    var six = $('#six').scrollTop();
    var seven = $('#seven').scrollTop();
    var eight = $('#eight').scrollTop();
    var nine = $('#nine').scrollTop();
    var ten = $('#ten').scrollTop();

    if (e.which == 72) {
      var distance = Math.abs(pos - home);
      var scrollSpeed = distance * speed;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: home
      }, scrollSpeed);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 home">
    <h1 id="welcome">Welcome</h1>
    <p id="intro">Type a number 1-9, 0 is for 10 and typing 'h' will bring you back to the home screen</p>
  </div>
</section>

<a href="http://www.buildinamsterdam.com/cases" target="_blank">
  <section id="one">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 one">
      <h1 id="h1">Horizontal Scroll</h1>
      <p id="p1">A page or section that scrolls horizontally instead of vertically. A unique way to shorten a page.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>

<a href="http://hollow.org.uk/" target="_blank">
  <section id="two">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 two">
      <h1 id="h2">Gallery Zoom</h1>
      <p id="p2">Have items in my gallery slowly zoom in or out.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>

<a href="http://www.cartoonnetworkstudios.com/" target="_blank">
  <section id="three">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 three">
      <h1 id="h3">Interactive Name</h1>
      <p id="p3">Have a home page with my name in large lettering, each letter when hovered over would have an effect, bringing up a word that describes my services.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>

<a href="http://ony-france.com/origin" target="_blank">
  <section id="four">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 four">
      <h1 id="h4">Overlapping Gallery</h1>
      <p id="p4">Have Pieces in my gallery set up on a parallax scroll and overlap each other slightly.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>

<a href="https://my.pottermore.com/patronus" target="_blank">
  <section id="five">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 five">
      <h1 id="h5">Mouse Trail</h1>
      <p id="p5">Have a mouse trail on my landing page that is made up of 1's and 0's to signify binary code.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>

<a href="https://spotify---bastille.appspot.com/" target="_blank">
  <section id="six">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 six">
      <h1 id="h6">Moving Text</h1>
      <p id="p6">Having a parallax image has become pretty common but having other elements on the page also move with the mouse is rather unique.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>

<a href="https://www.oasen.nl/home/mijn-oasen" target="_blank">
  <section id="seven">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 seven">
      <h1 id="h7">Element Loading</h1>
      <p id="p7">Have elements load at separate times, rather than everything loading at once.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>

<a href="http://counterclimate.converse.com/" target="_blank">
  <section id="eight">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 eight">
      <h1 id="h8">Mouse Distortion</h1>
      <p id="p8">Cause the mouse to distort certain things on a page when you move over it.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>

<a href="https://www.sirinlabs.com/" target="_blank">
  <section id="nine">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 nine">
      <h1 id="h9">3D Translate</h1>
      <p id="p9">Have a 3D Orb where each piece of orb is a gallery piece which translates out on hover.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>

<a href="http://piratecode.ru/en/" target="_blank">
  <section id="ten">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 ten">
      <h1 id="h10">Countdown</h1>
      <p id="p10">A dynamic loading page that counts down or has some kind of display that will count down.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</a>
```

Comment: Might be because the `keyCode` of `h` is 104 and not 72? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It' because 72 is a [JavaScript char code](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) which can be accessed using `e.keyCode`. More commonly in jQuery `e.which` is used and is the key code of the event like `keydown` or `keyup`. For example `h` is 104:

```
if(e.which == 104) {}
```

Comment: Every keycode site i've got to has said it is 72, can you link me to the one you are using since mine are all apparently wrong?

Comment: I didn't use any site, I just added `console.log(e.which)` inside the `keypress` function, then I pressed `h` and looked at the console what number it was showing.

Comment: Thanks I'll find the keycodes that way from now on, has there been a recent update to that info or something? Every site says the wrong codes.

Comment: I used console to find the keycode for '1' and wrote an else if statement but it doesn't work even though 'h' is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/rmkxt6L8/

Comment: @Shniper Try `$('#one').position().top` instead of `$('#one').scrollTop()`

Comment: It also works with var xxx = $('#xxx').offset().top; as I commented

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs

https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

for mozilla the keypress will work and e.which will be 72

```
$("#target").on("keypress", function(e) {


    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var speed = 1.5;
    var home = $('#home').scrollTop();
    var one = $('#one').scrollTop();
    var two = $('#two').scrollTop();
    var three = $('#three').scrollTop();
    var four = $('#four').scrollTop();
    var five = $('#five').scrollTop();
    var six = $('#six').scrollTop();
    var seven = $('#seven').scrollTop();
    var eight = $('#eight').scrollTop();
    var nine = $('#nine').scrollTop();
    var ten = $('#ten').scrollTop();

  console.log(e.keyCode)

    if(e.which == 72) {
        var distance = Math.abs(pos - home);
        var scrollSpeed = distance * speed;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: home
        }, scrollSpeed);
    }
});
```

for chrome keydown event can be used for the same and e.keyCode = 72

```
$("#target").on("keydown", function(e) {


    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var speed = 1.5;
    var home = $('#home').scrollTop();
    var one = $('#one').scrollTop();
    var two = $('#two').scrollTop();
    var three = $('#three').scrollTop();
    var four = $('#four').scrollTop();
    var five = $('#five').scrollTop();
    var six = $('#six').scrollTop();
    var seven = $('#seven').scrollTop();
    var eight = $('#eight').scrollTop();
    var nine = $('#nine').scrollTop();
    var ten = $('#ten').scrollTop();

  console.log(e.keyCode)

    if(e.keyCode == 72) {
        var distance = Math.abs(pos - home);
        var scrollSpeed = distance * speed;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: home
        }, scrollSpeed);
    }
});
```

working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/skp6kLzw/